# matters that are unique to the programming profession

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Now that [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is [almost out of beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related), can we think about removing the fourth bullet point in the [SO faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) concerning what questions are acceptable?

- matters that are unique to the
  programming profession

A question that is on-topic by this criterion is either

1. Already on topic by one of the other three criteria
2. Not already on topic by one of the other three criteria

If it is already on topic, then the criterion in question adds nothing to it: It's already on topic. If it is not already on topic, but would be by the fourth criterion, then isn't it a better fit for [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Here's a list of questions that I think have about zero place on SO but which would be a good fit for Programmers.

- [GitHub Etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309679/github-etiquette/4318806)  - compilers don't care about etiquette.
- [Does anybody know how Java 7 will affect Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308010/does-anybody-know-how-java-7-will-affect-scala) - Asks for opinions
- [Why is it customary to put many closing parentheses on one line in Lisp-based languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304925/why-is-it-customary-to-put-many-closing-parentheses-on-one-line-in-lisp-based-lan) - Ho Brah! You want one history lesson?
- [What are the chronological steps in building a cross browser compatible site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309618/what-are-the-chronological-steps-in-building-a-cross-browser-compatible-site) - This is a workflow question. Different people have different workflows and the best one is a matter of opinion. It's not "How do I implement feature *X* in a cross browser way?" That's a programming (or at least mark-up) question. This isn't that.

I've found these by looking through the highest voted questions on SO. I appreciate the fact that some of them are sort of borderline but I don't think any of them have any business on SO. Am I just a fascist?

Comment: Kudos for understanding criteria/criterion.